# Does removing a component from a container's instance remain in memory?

Tags: java, oop, memory

I have a container which switches its main content between several screen-sized panes. I'm not using `CardLayout`, instead I'm using `remove(previous); add(current); validate();`

In this container I have data fields for each of these panes, which are initialized at startup so that I can easily just switch the reference between them.

**My question:**

If you remove the previous pane and add the new / current one, does the memory taken up by the previous pane's instance object remain in memory?

Because I considered setting the previous pane to null and re-creating the current pane before adding it to the container in an attempt to lower memory usage, but wasn't sure if it would actually make any difference.

Thanks. :)

**EDIT**: This isn't actually my class but it demonstrates how I'm going about switching views:

```
public class ViewManager {

   public static final int VIEW_LOGIN = 0;
   public static final int VIEW_CALENDAR = 1;
   public static final int VIEW_HELP = 2;
   public static final int VIEW_SETTINGS = 3;
   public static final int VIEW_PREFERENCES = 4;
   public static final int VIEW_STATS = 5;

   private static LoginPane login = new LoginPane();
   private static CalendarView calendar = new CalendarView();
   private static HelpPane help = new HelpPane();
   private static SettingsPane accountSettings = new SettingsPane();
   private static PreferencesPane preferences = new PreferencesPane();
   private static StatsPane stats = new StatsPane();

   private static int previousView;

   private static Object [] views = {login, calendar, help, accountSettings, preferences, stats};

   // Without settings old views to null and re-creating incoming view request
   public static void switchTo(int currentView){
      if(currentView == previousView) return;

      MainFrame.getContent().remove(views[previousView]);
      MainFrame.getContent().add(views[currentView]);        
      MainFrame.getContent().validate();
   }

    // Settings to null and re-creating incoming view request
   public static void switchToNullify(int currentView){
      if(currentView == previousView) return;

      MainFrame.getContent().remove(views[previousView]);
      views[previousView] = null;

      if(currentView == VIEW_LOGIN)            views[VIEW_LOGIN] = new LoginPane();
      else if(currentView == VIEW_CALENDAR)    views[VIEW_CALENDAR] = new CalendarView();
      else if(currentView == VIEW_HELP)        views[VIEW_HELP] = new HelpPane();
      else if(currentView == VIEW_SETTINGS)    views[VIEW_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS] = new SettingsPane();
      else if(currentView == VIEW_PREFERENCES) views[VIEW_PREFERENCES] = new PreferencesPane();
      else if(currentView == VIEW_STATS)       views[VIEW_STATS] = new StatsPane();

      MainFrame.getContent().add(views[currentView]);
      MainFrame.getContent().validate();
   }
}
```

Comment: By the way, the scope of this question is beyond Java Swing. It really applies to OOP as a whole (i.e. [eliminating obsolete object references](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780137150021/ch02lev1sec6)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you remove the previous pane and add the new / current one, does
>   the memory taken up by the previous pane's instance object remain in
>   memory?

Yes, unless you remove *all* references to that object. Once you've done that, it'll be eligible for garbage collection.

> Because I considered setting the previous pane to `null`...

Good idea!

Comment: See also [Handling memory leaks in Java programs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-leaks/).

Comment: Setting them to null ensures GC, but that means I have to re-create the object again when I'm switching back to it later. Could you please elaborate on `unless you remove all references to that object`?

Comment: @paranoid-android, If recreating the previous panel is expensive, then I suppose you'll just have to cache it, but it will take up space (i.e. memory). And by that comment, I meant any object other than the object itself that holds a reference to it (e.g. a map, a list, another class), must set the reference to null in order to allow the object to be eligible for GC.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense after reading @trashgod's resource as well. Thanks both.